# How to increase accuracy of decision tree classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

How to increase accuracy of decision tree classifier?
I wrote a code for decision tree with Python using `sklearn`. I want to check the accuracy of that code so I have split data in `train` and `test`. I have tried to "play" with  `test_size` and `random_state` but I always get the accuracy from 0.33 to 0.45 (33%-45%). I do now know what am I doing wrong, so please help me if you know whats the problem.

I have downloaded dataset from here (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/concrete+compressive+strength). Data is in excel file, it has 9 columns and 1300 rows, I have read it with pandas.

I made a 10th column, where I calculated "Class of concrete", thats a string value. Tenth So 10th column has 15 different string values ("concrete classes"). I want to predict concrete class based on first 8 columns

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def predict_concrete_class(input_data, cement, blast_fur_slug,fly_ash,
                            water, superpl, coarse_aggr, fine_aggr, days):

    data_for_tree = concrete_strenght_class(input_data)

    variable_list = []
    result_list = []

    for index, row in data_for_tree.iterrows():
        variable = row.tolist()
        variable = variable[0:8]

        variable_list.append(variable)
        result_list.append(row[-1])

    #accuracy of prediction(splitting the dataset)
    var_train, var_test, res_train, res_test = train_test_split(variable_list, result_list, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

    decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(var_train, res_train)

    input_values = [cement, blast_fur_slug, fly_ash, water, superpl, coarse_aggr, fine_aggr, days]

    #calculating the accuracy
    score = decision_tree.score(var_test, res_test)
    score = round(score*100, 2)

    prediction = decision_tree.predict([input_values])
    prediction = prediction[0]

    accuracy_info = "Accuracy of concrete class prediction: " + str(score) + " %\n"
    prediction_info = "Prediction of future concrete class after "+ str(days)+" days: "+ str(prediction) 
    info = "\n" + accuracy_info + prediction_info

    return info
```

Comment: Hi Alexsandar, 
While I agree that your accuracy score is not impressive, have you tried using other classifiers to get a benchmark of what accuracy score you should expect from your task? 
Once you will have a better idea of what you should expect, the most natural choice to improve your model would be to tune it. Decision Trees have a bunch of hyperparameters you may want to adjust to improve your score (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)

Comment: First of all, I'd be curious about your data, rather than the model itself: count of samples, count of classes, how balanced dataset is, do data scaled etc. 

The thing is if you have 100 classes and 100 samples, and getting 0.33 accuracy - means you performing 33X times better then random which not so bad for not tuned classifier.

Comment: @Platon I have downloaded data from here [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/concrete+compressive+strength). Its a excel file with 1030 rows and 9 columns. I want to predict based on 8 columns

Comment: @Aleksandar as far as I can see from data if you want to predict 9-th column you should use Regression model and count mean squared error for example rather then using classification algorithms.

Comment: I made a 1oth column, where I calculated "Class of concrete", thats a string value. So 10th column has 15 different string values ("concrete classes"). I want to predict concrete class based on first 8 columns